# Digital Ocean and Dokku plus Play had to use 2gb RAM Machine

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

So i recently installed a play application using Dokku on Digital Ocean following the tutorial provided. The only issue was i kept getting an error when pushing to the server saying i didnt have enough memory to compile the app. I ended up having to upgrade to the 20/mo 2GB machine for it to finally work. The tutorial says you can use the smallest droplet. When i check my memory usage on the droplet im using about 1.2 GB but java is only using 8% of total. Where is my memory going? Is play taking all the memory? How can i use the smaller droplet and play still?

Comment: Have you tried a swap file for your memory on your droplet? I am also interested in this setup but haven't tried on a droplet yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gunhan said in comment initially you should add swap space like described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04). If problem persists run this command

```
echo 1 >  /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

in terminal and to restart your vm to be sure. For detailed information about this command please read [here](http://tonylixu.blogspot.com.tr/2014/01/linux-kernel-tuning-swappiness-and.html).